# writing a unit test for an angular directive that requires ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and trying to figure out how to set it all up. I have the following directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hntb-utils')
        .directive('notZero', notZero);

    //notZero.$inject = [];

    function notZero() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: '='
        };

        function link(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$validators.notZero = function (value) {
                return value != 0;
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

This directive (if added as an attribute not-zero to an element that also uses ng-model) ensures that the model value is not zero by adding a validator to the ngModelController.

I am trying to figure out how to test this directive. I figure I should probably have something like:

```
it("should ensure model is not zero", function () {
...
});
```

I am just really stuck on the implementation. I know I should use angular-mocks but how? What do I mock up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) service to compile an input element with an `ngModel` directive and `notZero` directive. Get the `ngModelController` of that element by using the [`.controller()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods) method. Afterwards, manipulate the scope model of that element to apply multiple test cases.

Here is a **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RysHgTmJSPUi0ia0lCiL?p=preview)**.

```
describe('notZero', function() {

  var scope, 
    ngModel;

  beforeEach(module('hntb-utils'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var input = $compile('<input type="number" ng-model="model" not-zero />')(scope);

    ngModel = input.controller('ngModel');

  }));

  it("should validate a non-zero number as a valid number", function () {

    scope.model = -1;
    scope.$apply();
    expect(ngModel.$error.notZero).toBeFalsy();

    scope.model = 1;
    scope.$apply();
    expect(ngModel.$error.notZero).toBeFalsy();

  });

  it("should validate a zero number as an invalid number", function() {

    scope.model = 0;
    scope.$apply();
    expect(ngModel.$error.notZero).toBeTruthy();

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, for this. The test is working and I really appreciate the help. I have one question though. I am wondering why angular-mocks is needed. I guess I am having trouble understanding where the dependency on angular ends and the dependency on angular-mocks begins. I mean, inject is a jasmine function? and then $compile and $rootscope are added as global variables by angular-mocks? Which library provides the module function? Is there any way you can break down the test a little in the sense of which dependency is doing what?

Comment: Both `module()` and `inject()` function are from the `angular-mocks` library.

Comment: Ok, one more slightly replated question, how would I go about debugging a test? Is there any utility where I could specify the dependencies (kind of like karma) and the test and it would open a web page (say in chrome) where I could step through the test? Could this be done via karma (when I run my karma task it opens and then closes the browser...Thanks.

Comment: Why do you mean by specifying dependencies? client side dependencies such as 3rd part angularjs modules?

Comment: I mean any files that are needed to run the test including my own modules, 3rd party modules, angular-mocks/angular source etc.

Comment: Karma has a `files` option in its configuration where you put all the files that you need to be executed, all the source code and test code that want to be included.